# Can I run 10 gauge wire in 3/4" schedule 40, (100 feet) to a 20 amp outlet for a 110 pool pump?

Tags: wiring

Can I run 10 gauge wire in 3/4" schedule 40,(100 feet)to a 20 amp outlet for a 110 pool pump ? I am concerned about amps & voltage drop to a sensitive 110V swimming pool pump.

and......Regarding the GFI, is it best to use a GFI outlet or a GFI breaker.

Comment: What size pool pump?  Can it run on 240 volt?

Comment: Yes, what HP rating is this pool pump?

Comment: Yes, when computing voltage drop, choose amps carefully.  Don't use breaker trip, use what the loads will actually be.

Answer (score 1):

A 1 Hp pump could be run on a 20 amp circuit using #10 awg wire at 100’ within the recommended 3% voltage drop.
At start up the voltage drop may be slightly higher than 3% but a 1 Hp motor by code will calculate at 16 amps so that is the largest motor that could be used within recommended values. As far as schedule 40 if the conduit is protected by location it could be used. Note rigid 3/4” can handle 9 thhn / thwn just about all thhn is dual rated thwn for use in wet locations and conduit outside is a wet location.  If buried 18” below the surface or if mounted above 8’ schedule 40 will be fine. Schedule 40 has to be protected not exposed to damage.